# How to aggregate the rawContacts using aggregationException content correclty

Tags: android, android-contacts, aggregation

I'm backing up and restoring contacts, I'm able to do it, but while aggregation of rawcontacts for linked contacts(joined contacts) using `ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions`
If i join 3 contacts, say Contact A (master) and Contact B (linked) and C (linked)
I do the backup ,and restore,for the newly created id's with correct mapping, I'm updating the `ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI` with following code:

```
private boolean aggregateContactLinks() {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        int listCount = linkList.size();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
        Log.i(tag, "aggregating contacts");
        for (int i=0; i<listCount; i++) {

                values.put(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1,
                        linkList.get(i).newId1);
                values.put(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2,
                        linkList.get(i).newId2);
                values.put(AggregationExceptions.TYPE,
                        AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_TOGETHER);

                Log.i(tag," new master id(id1) :"+linkList.get(i).newId+"\nlinkid2 :"+newId2);
                Log.i(tag,
                        "result :"
                                + cr.update(AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI,
                                        values, null, null));
                Log.i(tag, "\nupdated one contact");

        }
        values.clear();
        return true;
    }
```

output , on phone i can see the linked content but in display name of contact is **c** instead of **a**

**before backup**
[image]

**after backup, deleting the contacts and after restore**
[image]

can anyone know where exactly im going wrong,thanks in advance

Comment: How are you doing the "backup" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tell Android contact provider that it should use the specific raw contact name for aggregated contact (not display names of linked contacts B and C but the display name of master contact A), you may use **RawContactsColumn.NAME_VERIFIED**. Simply set it to "1" for your master raw contact after updating aggregation exceptions.

I found this trick in the standard Contacts application's
[code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts):

```
// Mark the original contact as "name verified" to make sure that the contact
// display name does not change as a result of the join
if (verifiedNameRawContactId != -1) {
    Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(
            ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, verifiedNameRawContactId));
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.NAME_VERIFIED, 1);
    operations.add(builder.build());
}
```

RawContactsColumn interface is protected, so you should use "name_verified" as column name. Because of the fact that RawContactsColumn isn't open, maybe you should also check if "name_verified" column exists before updating to avoid crashes.

Comment: "name_verified" fiels is removed in android M (Preview 2)